# trouble associating a listView id with findViewby() in android

Tags: android, xml, android-listview, android-xml

I am trying to populate a list view, and am trying to select my listview in my main with:

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main.xml.id);
```

My folder structure for XML is:

> res>layout>activity_main.xml

and my `main_activity.xml` file looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I think this is a simple mistake of me not fully understanding how the xml id value works in android.

Comment: Are you extending ListActivity or activity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the below

In OnCreate

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Change listview in xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: Awesome,, worked. (Need to wait a minute before I can accept as right answer.) But now that it worked, why. I dont exactly understand whats going on here.

Comment: you are extending listactivity so what you did is right. you can do  setListAdapter(youradapter) if you extend listActivity you need to have this `android:id="@android:id/list"`. i saw that after posting your code in the link/ instead of this `lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main.xml.id)` you should have `ListView lv = getListView()`

Comment: it's also good to keep the default android IDs (`android:id/list`). In which case you do `findViewById(android.R.id.list)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try like below:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ist);
```

and in xml change id of listview like below:

```
android:id="@+id/list"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the activity code file (java)

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Answer (score 0):

In onCreate() you will find `setContenctView(R.layout.activity_main);` If not then you must add it. Make sure it is set to the xml activity you want to work with in the code java file. Then you can easily refer to the listView by using

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Also the id in xml of a control is defined in the following form

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >
</ListView>
```